# Taking input from user within a printed text

Tags: c++, input

I want to take input from the user in between the () in the given "cout" statement, in place of the '_'

```
cout<<"Warning! you are going to resize, which may result in loss of data are you sure you want to continue: Y/N(_)";
```

How may I be able to do it? Are there any escape sequence for doing it? Or any other way?

Comment: use `cin` afterwards.simple

Comment: What CLI are you using?

Comment: You can try something with the `\b` escape sequence if it works for you. `\b` moves the cursor one character backward.

Comment: but that does not place the users input within the bracket @Sourav Ghosh.

Comment: I am a WIndows 8.1 user, i am using visual c++ 6.0  @CaptainGiraffe

Comment: @JoyRamSenGupta why would you want to do that? Just let it print and then take the input from user.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I am a novice programmer and want to learn that feature if available

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Sounds like the OP wants to implement some kind of ASCII screen form. I'd recommend to have a look at [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Comment: @JoyRamSenGupta No that feature isn't available natively, you'll either need to provide an implementation for your specific terminal program's capabilities, or use a 3rd party library as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for your worthy comment! ncurses is going to be difficult for me to use as i have started learning the prog concepts ! Can you give me a clear idea how can i start using this library?

Comment: @JoyRamSenGupta You'll probably need to start out becoming familiar with their basics: http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this code fragment:

```
scanf("(%s)",&str)
```

Comment: can you please brief with a code ! This is not working !